# Как передать JS-переменную Ajax"ом в PHP скрипт

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

есть JS-переменная `var str = 15;`

Ее нужно как то передать PHP-скрипту и число `15` прировнять другой переменной, допустим `$str`

Как я понял это можно только с помощью AJAX, а я в нем вообще не разбираюсь

Помогите, кто-нибудь, задача простая, а решение мне не по силам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на `jQuery`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = 15;
$.ajax({
  url: '/test.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: {post_data: str},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});

</script>
```

Тогда ваше число `15` придет в скрипт `test.php`, а обрабатывать так:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['post_data']; // ну или другие манипуляции
```

Пример при запуске выведет ваше число в консольку браузера. Если вывело - работает :)

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = 15;
$.ajax({
  url: '/test.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: {post_data: str},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data['value']);
  }
});

</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = $_POST['post_data'];
$response = array();
$response['value'] = $data;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Желательно структурировать данные, а не кидать их голым echo. json для этого подходит лучше всего.