# Проблема обработки клиентского запроса на сервере

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Отправляю с js данные на сервер, которые принимает php. Данные отправляются успешно, но на сервере не принимаются. В чем может быть проблема?

код js

```
let ob = {
    name: 'alex'
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/index.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: ob
});
```

код php

```
<?php

session_start();

$_POST = json_decode( file_get_contents("php://input"), true );

$a = $_POST["name"];

 if(isset($a)) {
    echo 'true';
}

?>
```

Comment: оставьте просто `data: ob` и получите потом `$_POST['name']`, не надо всего вот этого что  у вас понаписано

Comment: [Пример ajax запроса и обработки его на сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/868971/256707)